# How to access the json data in react native mentioned in below pattern?

Tags: json, react-native

The json data is in the below pattern. And the Json data is coming from backend and getting through api and storing in a state variable.

```
{
    "message": "user created successfully",
    "status": "success",
    "student": {
        "class": "10",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "name": "User",
        "password": "user",
        "phone_number": "some phone number",
        "school": "1",
        "section": "a"
    }
}
```

I have stored the data which is returned through api in a state variable.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        jsonData: ''
    }
}
```

And tried accessing using below fashion.

```
this.state.jsonData.status
```

but not able to access. How can I access the status value in react?

Comment: can you show how are you calling the api? if you are calling your api in `componentDidMount` and in the response you need to set the state value as `this.setState({jsonData: result})` like this

Comment: yeah I have did the same. And the jsonData variable contains the data in the same format which is shown above. @AnkushRishi

Comment: What does it mean "not able to access"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: can you update your post and show the code how did you set the state so that I can figure out the problem easily

Answer (score 1):

Please check type of `jsonData` in state when you call it using `typeof` or `instanceof`.

It maybe by you store fetched data in `string` type without check and manipulating.

If it is `string` type, convert it using `JSON.parse`